# Django IntegrityError of this overriding save method

Tags: python, django, overriding

**My Model**

```
class Worksite(models.Model):
    firm = models.ForeignKey('Firm', verbose_name='Firma', related_name="worksites", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name="Şantiye Adı")
```

**My save method**

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.slug:
        self.slug = self.get_unique_slug()
        os.mkdir(BASE_DIR+'/file/'+slugify(str(self.firm).replace('ı','i'))+'/'+self.slug)
    return super(Worksite, self).save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

**My UpdateView**

```
class WorksiteUpdateView(generic.edit.UpdateView):
    template_name = 'firm/worksite_update.html'
    model = Worksite
    form_class = WorksiteForm

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse('firm:worksite_list')
```

> IntegrityError : (1062, "Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'")

If the save method is deleted, the update process is successful. but this time the folder can not be created. so save method is necessary. but this error is annoying.
where is the mistakes?
Help pls.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are calling parent's method incorrectly? Try `return super(Worksite, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` (by removing extra `self` argument).

Answer (score 1):

It's because you pass `self` argument when calling superclass method - `super().save()`. It should work fine, if you delete it:

```
return super(Worksite, self).save( *args, **kwargs)
```